# Static Route to Subnet via VPN

Tags: routing, vpn

Trying to access a network via a static route.

My PC is on Windows 10 and I am connecting to a remote network via VPN.
My local network is 192.168.178.1/24. 
My PC's VPN client address is 10.35.0.144.
The VPN gateway is 10.35.0.129.

Via the VPN I have access to a 10.1.0.0/24 network, where a router, IP: 10.1.1.175, enables access to another 10.124.193.0/24 network.

I need to be able to manage devices on this 10.124.193.0/24 network. I added a static route: "route add 10.124.194.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.175", which I thought might do the trick.

However, when I do a tracert to 10.124.193.x, I see that traffic is not going through the VPN as expected, but hits my local gateway (192.168.178.1) and stops there. I expected a couple of hops like: 10.35.0.129, then 10.1.1.175, then 10.124.193.x.

The output of the route table below is partly in German, I hope that is ok, and still comprehensible.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 10.124.193.6

tracing route to 10.124.193.6 over a maximum of 30 Hops

1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
  2  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]  reports: destination host unreachable
[image: route print]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a route, you need to give it the next hop. In your case, the next hop is `10.35.0.129`, but your configured next hop is not.

After that, you are trusting that the next hop has a route to then next hop in the path toward your destination. If not, you need to modify that router to have a route toward your destination. If you don't have access to that router, this question is off-topic since you need to have control over the network about which you are asking questions.

Comment: Each one of the hops has access to the next hop. From my PC I can ping the router that has a static route to my destination network. So that is good. I can ping 10.1.1.175, which has a route to 10.124.193.0/24. The question is, how do I set the different hops on Windows CLI?

Comment: Questions about configuring your PC are off topic here, but you can ask on [su].

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect you don't have control of the network. Routing works by each hop looking at the destination address and looking up which way to send the traffic for the next hop. Having a complete path to the destination doesn't do any good unless each router in the path has a route to the final destination and knows where to send the traffic. You don't program that into Windows on one end only.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is simply not possible on Windows. On a MAC it works with the static route I have configured.

Comment: MacOS might automatically substitute the local gateway for the remote gateway that you configure which Windows doesn't. However, actually configuring remote gateways generally isn't possible.